# React element should contain desired properties. Why desired?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#elements-describe-the-tree) in the blog Dan Abramov wrote the react elements should contain desired properties for DOM-elements or components.

What did he mean by desired? Why desired? Did he mean not strict? If it was some sort of recommendation, where should it have applied? What/who is responsible to make decision on which exact properties should be passed to component or DOM-element?

Comment: I guess what he means is that when you create an React element which 'replaces' some raw DOM element, you should copy and handle it's available properties inside the React element. Example : <Input /> should handle type="text" etc. prop correctly (passing it to underlying input dom node or mimic it's behavior)

Comment: > when you create an React element which 'replaces'

@Goran.it do you mean `React.Component` or the element of React though?

Comment: Element of React - which is the more or less the same anyway as when you create an React element you extend React.Component.

Comment: @Goran.it I'm not sure I can understand you. React element is just a simple JS object which describes components and DOM-elements. So the desired properties are not related to DOM-element only, but to components also. My questions is why are the desired properties just desired?

Comment: Because you might decide you don't need / won't implement `title` attribute for example